# SQL Query on Seperating into Category

Tags: sql, database

I have two columns, Type of asset and Total Amount Sale. I want to divide them into categories, high value and low value. The type of asset are PC240, PC250, PC400, PC500, PC1000.

If I were to set the minimum sale to the following. Please can someone help me how would I do it. Do I need to create another table to input this Minimum Sale?

[image]

Note: this minimum sale I got it from Excel file.

[image]

Comment: It's recommended to provide data / code / and additional stuff like error messages / exceptions etc. as (formatted) Text rather than attached imaged when asking questions because the info can get found via web search etc. that way and get copied&pasted by the readers who want to help rather than retyping all that stuff and having to buy new optical glasses for decipherment

Comment: Why can't you just group the table to find min and max values like `select subtype, min(TotalAmount) as Low, max(TotalAmount) as High from SomeTable group by subtype`. Are you trying to see min and max as 2 values in the result? The partition could help in that scenario with dance rank may be.